# Drupal 7 Colorbox module doesn't see his own library

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, colorbox

i try to install Colorbox on Drupal, but i have some problems. So Drupal doesn't see colorbox library in `sites/all/modules/librares` folder. I have all files in sites/all/modules/librares/colorbox. I read in Internet one solution and move JS files to new colorbox folder and JS files now in `sites/all/modules/librares/colorbox/colorbox` folder. It's not working too.

I install clear Drupal, next install Libraries module, copy Colorbox library and install Colorbox module, but i still have

> The Colorbox plugin library could not be found. You need to download the Colorbox plugin, extract the archive and place the colorbox directory in the sites/all/libraries directory on your server.
>   Yes, i try create another colorbox folder in colorbox folder and move JS files but it's not working.

Please, anyone can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download colorbox plugin inside the folder `sites/all/libraries`.

Which means that the `jquery.colorbox.js` file path should be `sites/all/libraries/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js`.

Comment: Thanks, after extraction I just had to rename colorbox 1.x... into colorbox, in the libraries folder and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the colorbox-1.x.zip unzipped to a directory named colorbox-1.x.

To get the error message to go away, I needed to manually rename colorbox-1.x to colorbox.

```
#cd /sites/all/libraries
#unzip colorbox-1.x.zip
#mv colorbox-1.x colorbox
```

The error message went away after I did that